# using Ajax with rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

This might be a beginner question (I'm new to Rails 3), but I'm trying to use Ajax once a user clicks on a link, initiate a $.post call, and do some changes in the server-side.

In the _share partial, I have:

```
%a.fbbutton.twitterbutton{:id => "twitter"}       (href="javascript:window.open(%22http://twitter.com/share?text=Does anyone know a #{@branch.title} @branchly%21&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.branch.ly/branches/#{@branch.id}%22,%22Share%22,%22width=500,height=250,scrollbars=yes%22)" class="twitter button" onclick="submitWithAjax();") Tweet
```

The function SubmitwithAjax() is in application.js file:

```
function submitWithAjax() {
$.post('background_forward', $(this).serialize(), null, "script");  
     return false; }
```

In my routes I have:

```
match 'background_forward', :to => "branches#background_forward"
```

I just need to have the submitwithAjax function go to a specific method in my server. Would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your js is fine so far, now you just need to add the correct action on the `BranchesController` that responds to a POST, as well as registering that method in your routes.rb (I believe it's a GET by default).

Comment: Ok so I managed to get to the method I want within the controller, but now it raises a 500 Internal server error because I didn't specify a respond format. The problem is, I don't want to have a respond format, I just want it do nothing. It gives the error: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template branches/background_forward, application/background_forward with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :jbuilder, :haml]}. Searched in: